# asp.net cannot find class

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono

I have some asp.net that I developed and is working just fine on a windows machine but now I'm trying to run it on a machine running Ubuntu and Mono 2.4.4 and ASP.NET 2.0 and getting errors.

I have some classes in my App_Code directory, such as `DatabaseSingleton.cs`, `Functions.cs` and `NotAllowedException.cs`. All of them are using the namespace `aspapp`.

Anyway, when trying to run a file (`Login.aspx.cs`) that uses the `DatabaseSingleton` class, I get that `CS0103: The name 'DatabaseSingleton' does not exist in the current context`. However, in a different file that isn't using `DatabaseSingleton` but is using `NotAllowedException`, I get a similar but a different error: `CS0246: The type or namespace name 'NotAllowedException' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?`. All the files are in the namespace `aspapp` and has `using aspapp` in the files.

Are there anything I need to add in the web.config to be able to access these files on mono?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you are pointing to mod-mono-server2 in your .conf file You can compile the .cs in one dll and move it to Bin directory